# Can we add relative search path for 'Locator' tool in QtCreator?

Tags: search, qt-creator

Is there a way I could add a relative search path (relative to the current open project) for the **locator tool** in QtCreator? I use this tool frequently to open files in my current project. I have files of extensions other than *.qml & *.js which I would want to locate using this tool.

Answer (score 0):

The locator lists all files you have referrenced in your open projects. So you could list the files e.g. in "OTHER_FILES" of your qmake project. For other buildsystems this might not work though.

You could also define a different project for the extra files and open that together with the main project using the session feature in Creator.

Or you can use locator to open the files directly by using "f path/to/file".